# Intersections of wires in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I want to make nodes at intersection

[image]

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}
         \newcommand\T{1.5}                  
         \foreach \a in {30,90,...,330}
         \draw (\a:\T) to[short,*-*] (\a+120:\T);
          \draw (90:\T) to[short,-o] +(90:0.4)node[right] {C}; 
          \draw (270:\T) to[short,-o] +(270:0.4)node[left] {D};   
         \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the partway operator to trisect the sides of the triangle. Replace

```
\draw (\a:\T) to[short,*-*] (\a+120:\T);
```

by

```
\draw let \p1=(\a:\T), \p2=(\a+120:\T) in
  (\p1) to[short,*-*] ($(\p1)!1/3!(\p2)$) -- (\p2);
```

This will draw a black dot at the origin of each line and at 1/3 of the line. This is sufficient for drawing all dots.

If you want to access the intersections by name for adding labels or further connections, add `coordinate` instructions to the draw command.

```
\draw let \p1=(\a:\T), \p2=(\a+120:\T) in
  (\p1) coordinate (\a a)
        to[short,*-*] ($(\p1)!1/3!(\p2)$) coordinate (\a b)
        -- (\p2);
```

E.g., the first line drawn is the horizontal line from 30 to 150 degrees. The vertices will be named `(30a)`, `(30b)`, `(90b)`, and `(150a)`. Now the two nodes can be labeled by

```
\draw (30b) node[below]{B};
\draw (90b) node[below]{A};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\T{1.5}                  
  \foreach \a in {30,90,...,330}
    \draw let \p1=(\a:\T), \p2=(\a+120:\T) in
      (\p1) coordinate (\a a)
            to[short,*-*] ($(\p1)!1/3!(\p2)$) coordinate (\a b)
            -- (\p2);
  \draw (90a)  to[short,-o] +(0, 0.4)node[right] {C}; 
  \draw (270a) to[short,-o] +(0,-0.4)node[left ] {D};
  \draw (30b) node[below] {B};
  \draw (90b) node[below] {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here, pick your style : pin or label.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\T{1.5}                  
  \foreach \a in {30,90,...,330}
  {
    \draw (\a:\T) to[short,*-*] 
      node (myNode-\a) [red, pos={1/3}, circle, draw] {} 
      %node [blue!40, pos={-1/3}, circle, fill]{} % strange...
      (\a+120:\T) ;
  }
  \draw (90:\T) to[short,-o] +(90:0.4)node[right] {C}; 
  \draw (270:\T) to[short,-o] +(270:0.4)node[left] {D};   

  \node [circle, pin=below:A] at (myNode-30) {} ;
  \node [circle, label=below:B] at (myNode-330) {} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```